# Convert JSON array to CSV using PHP

Tags: php, csv

i need to have the csv have the format of the first picture but im currently getting the second picture as a final result, how can i set it properly so MailChimp can read the csv properly

```
        $jsonDecoded = json_decode(file_get_contents('emails.json', true), true);   

        $list = array(
            array('Email Address', 'First Name')
        );

        $timestamp = time();
        foreach($jsonDecoded as $entry)
        {
            $new = array($entry['email'], $entry['name']);
            $list[$timestamp] = $new;
        }

        //if old file exist delete
        $fp = fopen('emails.csv', 'w');
        foreach ($list as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

**Desired Output**
[image]

**Current Output with the above code**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main Issue I can see is you are overwriting the same field in the array, because you are using the same key in the loop

```
    //$timestamp = time(); - only set once, won't change
    foreach($jsonDecoded as $entry)
    {
        // this will update, but won't produce a different key for each iteration, 
        // because the loop might be faster than the smallest precision 
        // that the time() function can produce
        $timestamp = time();
                            
        $new = array($entry['email'], $entry['name']);
        $list[$timestamp] = $new;
    }
```

I don't see a use for the timestamp itself, so I suggest just use `array_push()` or the shorthand shown below

```
    foreach($jsonDecoded as $entry)
    {
        $new = array($entry['email'], $entry['name']);
        $list[] = $new; // this just adds the element to the end of the array
    }
```